# X2(para_id, account_id) conversion on relay chain resulting in `AccountIdConversionFailed`

Tags: xcm

We ran into an issue when trying to create a pool on the relay-chain from a contract on the parachain.

The issue is that when an interior location of a parachain (a contract account on Shibuya) sends an XCM transaction to the relay chain (Westend in this case), the origin is a descended origin MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X2(Parachain(2000), AccountId32 { ... }}. There is no location converter in Westend that supports this type of conversion. (**EDIT**: tested in a Zombienet setup)

This basically means a smart contract account would never be able to do a transaction on relay chain. Is that assumption true? Are there plans to allow a parachain interior account to send XCM transact instructions to relay chain?

If I add this line to Westend XCM config, it works:

https://gitlab.com/okalice/polkadot-sdk/-/blob/7d3040952117bb471a9a6d40744088c111e670d4/polkadot/xcm/xcm-builder/src/location_conversion.rs#L311

```
  - xcm::process_instruction: === WithdrawAsset(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(10000000000000) }]))
  - xcm::currency_adapter: withdraw_asset what: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: Here }), fun: Fungible(10000000000000) }, who: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X2(Parachain(2000), AccountId32 { network: Some(Westend), id: [212, 53, 147, 199, 21, 253, 211, 28, 97, 20, 26, 189, 4, 169, 159, 214, 130, 44, 133, 88, 133, 76, 205, 227, 154, 86, 132, 231, 165, 109, 162, 125] }) }
  - xcm::execute: !!! ERROR: FailedToTransactAsset("AccountIdConversionFailed")
  - xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: result: Err(ExecutorError { index: 1, xcm_error: FailedToTransactAsset("AccountIdConversionFailed"), weight: Weight { ref_time: 100015189000, proof_size: 100000000000 } })
  - xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: Execution errored at 1: FailedToTransactAsset("AccountIdConversionFailed") (original_origin: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(Parachain(2000)) })
  - xcm::process-message: XCM message execution incomplete, used weight: Weight(ref_time: 153499000, proof_size: 3593), error: FailedToTransactAsset("AccountIdConversionFailed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shibuya isn't connected to Westend but to a custom fork of Rococo relay chain. What setup are you using?

The line you modified breaks the purpose of that type. Instead, `HashedDescription` should be modified to use `DescribeAllTerminal`.

Comment: Thanks. This is in a Zombienet setup, I will edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: And thanks for: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/pull/3349 !

Comment: No problem! Hope it gets merged soon!